Duplicated and unrelated titles appear when searching for specific show using search field
I'm using the Jikan API to create an anime gallery of some sort, one of the features I wanted to include was to be able to search for a specific anime title within the gallery. My issue is that with my current search input field; despite specifying a show, it will show the specific title you searched for along with a couple of duplicated titles of an entirely different show.
Another issue I'm having is that despite setting a limit to how many shows data will be fetched, once I clear the search field, those same duplicates will be added onto the gallery despite the limitation.

App.js
import './App.css';
import AnimeGallery from './components/AnimeGallery';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Header from './components/Header';
import NavFilter from './components/NavFilter';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const animeApi = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v4/top/anime?type=tv&sfw=true&limit=12&filter=airing';

  const [animeList, setAnimeList] = useState([]);
  const [filteredAnime, setFilteredAnime] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAnimeGenre = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(animeApi);
      const data = await result.json();
      setAnimeList(data.data);
      setFilteredAnime(data.data);
    };
    fetchAnimeGenre();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <NavFilter animeList={animeList} setFilteredAnime={setFilteredAnime} />
      <AnimeGallery animeList={filteredAnime} />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

NavFilter.js
import '../styles/NavFilter.module.css'
import { useState } from 'react';

const NavFilter = ({ animeList, setFilteredAnime }) => {

    const [searchAnime, setSearchAnime] = useState('');

    const preventReload = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const handleSearchNav = (e) => {
        const searchTitle = e.target.value;
        setSearchAnime(searchTitle);

        if (searchTitle === '') {
            setFilteredAnime(animeList);
        } else {

            const filteredResults = animeList.filter(anime =>
                anime.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase())
            );

            setFilteredAnime(filteredResults);
        };
    }



    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <div className="w-full p-5 shadow-xl">
                    <ul className="flex justify-center tracking-wider text-sm">

                        <li>
                            <form
                                onSubmit={preventReload}
                            >
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    className="rounded-md px-8 py-1"
                                    placeholder="Search Anime..."
                                    value={searchAnime}
                                    onChange={handleSearchNav}></input>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default NavFilter;

AnimeGallery.js
import '../styles/AnimeGallery.module.css';

const AnimeGallery = ({ animeList }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <section className="anime-gallery container mx-auto grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 px-3 py-3 mt-20">
                {animeList.map((anime, index) => (
                    <article className="anime-card flex mx-3 my-2 rounded-lg h-72 bg-gray-dark shadow-md hover:-translate-y-3" key={anime.mal_id}>
                        <img className="anime-card-poster h-72" src={anime.images.jpg.image_url} alt={anime.title} />
                        <div className="anime-details p-3 w-full flex flex-col overflow-ellipsis overflow-auto">
                            <h3 className="anime-card-title text-xl tracking-wide text-balance text-baby-blue font-bold"> {anime.title}</h3>
                            <p className="anime-card-synopsis text-sm mt-2 text-gray-light"> Episodes: {anime.episodes || 'N/A'}</p>
                            <p className="anime-card-rating text-sm text-gray-light"> Rating: {anime.score}</p>
                            <p className="anime-card-status text-sm text-gray-light"> Status: {anime.status}</p>
                            <p className="anime-genres text-sm text-gray-light flex flex-wrap">
                                {anime.genres.map((genre) => (
                                    <p key={genre.mal_id} className="genre-btn px-2 bg-seafoam ms-1 rounded-lg mb-1 mt-2">{genre.name}</p>
                                ))}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                ))}
            </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default AnimeGallery;

Link to repo
For the duplicated titles I did try setting a key to equal the specific id of the show from the API but the duplicates are still present, and I'd also tried using a reduce method in place of my filter.
I also tried utilizing derived state and kept my state variable animeList as the only and entire list of the anime then one other state just for my search query so I could set the filter and specifications within my render, I didn't notice any changes with that approach either, but to be fair, I had to do a lot of research on the concept of derived state so perhaps I didn't implement it well.

There is a duplicate mal_id in the API response, hence rendering a list with that as a key causes problems while updating the list.
Try creating your own ids like below.
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAnimeGenre = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(animeApi);
      const data = await result.json();
      const transformedData = data.data.map((obj) => ({
        ...obj,
        id: crypto.randomUUID()
      }));
      setAnimeList(transformedData);
      setFilteredAnime(transformedData);
    };
    fetchAnimeGenre();
  }, []);

Make sure you also use this new id as the key in the list. key={anime.id}
